# Read more button problems with certain strings PHP & JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

I created a function using PHP and JavaScript. It works perfectly in most cases, but when I put messages into the posts that contain enters it doesn't work.

This is  the message causing problems:

```
"Hello,

I will try to use enters in this post. That is because
I want it to be very readable and stuff, and people like
things that are readable.

Kind Regards,
Rachid"
```

And here is my PHP code

```
<div class="guestbook-message" id="message_<?php echo $i;?>">
    <?php echo substr($guestBook[$i]['message'],0,140);
    if(strlen($guestBook[$i]['message']) > 140){ echo 
                        ".. <a class='read-more' 
                        onclick='expandMessage(
                        $i, \"{$guestBook[$i]['message']}\")'>ReadMore</a>";} ?>                
</div>
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```
function expandMessage(i, message) {
    document.getElementById('message_' + i).innerHTML = message +
    "<a onclick='shrinkMessage(" + i +",\"" + message + "\")' class='read-more'><br>Shrink Message</a>";
}
function shrinkMessage(i, message) {
    document.getElementById('message_' + i).innerHTML = message.substring(0, 140) +
    "..<a onclick='expandMessage(" + i +",\"" + message + "\")' class='read-more'> Read More</a>";
}
```

Please help me find the problem without using jQuery.

As per request the rendered HTML

```
<div class="post-header">Rachid | 2017-02-18 16:48:29 | Score: <img src="img/iconmonstr-thumbup.png"><img src="img/iconmonstr-thumbdown.png"></div>
    <div class="guestbook-message" id="message_18">
    Hello,

    I will try to use enters in this post. That is because
    I want it to be very readable and stuff, and people like
    things that are .. <a class='read-more' 
                        onclick='expandMessage(
                        18, "Hello,

    I will try to use enters in this post. That is because
    I want it to be very readable and stuff, and people like
    things that are readable.

    Kind Regards,
    Rachid")'>Read More</a> 
</div>
```

Comment: Nested Double quotes and newlines - press F12 to see the "unterminated literal" - then click the `<>` here in the editor and paste only the rendered HTML and javascript in

Comment: I am not seeing that in the console. Other strings without enters work fine so I don't think that is the problem @mplungjan but I will edit that HTML in

Comment: So it is not the quotes but the newlines.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it using `json_encode` function

```
<?php

   // your code goes here

   $a = "Hi

        How are you ";

   echo json_encode($a); // "Hi\n\nHow are you "
```

Comment: Can I do that inline in this code?
if(strlen($guestBook[$i]['message']) > 140){ echo 
                        ".. <a class='read-more' 
                        onclick='expandMessage(
                        $i, \"{$guestBook[$i]['message']}\")'>ReadMore</a>";}

Comment: @Veinq Yes, Of course ` if(strlen($guestBook[$i]['message']) > 140){ echo ".. <a class='read-more' onclick='expandMessage( $i, \"{json_encode($guestBook[$i]['message'])}\")'>ReadMore</a>";}`

Comment: That gives me a Notice: Array to string conversion unfortunately

Comment: I copy pasted the code from your comment and it didn't work. Do I need to use the backticks? maybe that was the problem. I tried simply echo-ing json_encode($guestBook[$i]['message']) which does work, so I will just tinker with the code a bit and try to make it work when using it as a parameter for my JS function.

Comment: No, You do not need them, Try this: 
if(strlen($guestBook[$i]['message']) > 140){ echo ".. <a class='read-more' onclick='expandMessage( $i, \"{json_encode("Hello,

I will try to use enters in this post. That is because
I want it to be very readable and stuff, and people like
things that are readable.

Kind Regards,
Rachid")}\")'>ReadMore</a>"‌​;}

Answer (score 0):

You need to use php function `nl2br`

```
nl2br($guestBook[$i]['message'])
```

[Function nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to swap the newlines for BR (nl2br) OR use PRE and a [backtick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```js
function expandMessage(i, message) {
  document.getElementById('message_' + i).innerHTML = message + "<a onclick='shrinkMessage(" + i + ",`" + message + "`)' class='read-more'><br>Shrink Message</a>";
}

function shrinkMessage(i, message) {
  document.getElementById('message_' + i).innerHTML = message.substring(0, 140) +
    "..<a onclick='expandMessage(" + i + ",`" + message + "`)' class='read-more'> Read More</a>";
}
```

```html
<div class="post-header">Rachid | 2017-02-18 16:48:29 | Score: <img src="img/iconmonstr-thumbup.png"><img src="img/iconmonstr-thumbdown.png"></div>
<div class="guestbook-message" id="message_18">
  Hello, I will try to use enters in this post. That is because I want it to be very readable and stuff, and people like things that are .. <a class='read-more' onclick='expandMessage(
                        18, `Hello,

    I will try to use enters in this post. That is because
    I want it to be very readable and stuff, and people like
    things that are readable.

    Kind Regards,
    Rachid`)'>Read More</a>
</div>
```

Here is a better way since it does not have text in the JavaScript and IE does not support the backtick (template literals)

```js
function toggleMessage(link) {
  link.previousSibling.classList.toggle("hide");
  link.textContent = link.textContent ==" Read More"?" Read Less":" Read More";
}
```

```css
.hide { display: none}
```

```html
<div class="post-header">Rachid | 2017-02-18 16:48:29 | Score: <img src="img/iconmonstr-thumbup.png"><img src="img/iconmonstr-thumbdown.png"></div>
<div class="guestbook-message" id="message_18">
  Hello, I will try to use enters in this post. That is because I want it to be very readable and stuff, and people like things that are <span class="hide">readable.

        Kind Regards,
        Rachid</span><a class='read-more' onclick="toggleMessage(this)"> Read More</a>
</div>
```

Comment: What do the backticks do?

Comment: It allows the newlines - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals see my update for another way

Comment: I like that this works, but I am really looking for a solution that keeps the newlines from user input. Thanks for your help.

Comment: They are still there but you need to convert to br anyway if you want to see them or wrap in a `<pre>`